# What is best practice for sticky-navigation homepage logo; should it refresh the page or just scroll back to top?

Tags: ux-field, response-time, seo

I'm currently a fresh Chief Marketing Officer Assistant for a brand in my country. While assessing our website's performance I've come across with this problem. As you know whenever you are in the middle of the website, the sticky-top navigation follows you through there but when I click on our sticky-top navigation bar's company logo, it just reloads the page. What is the best practice for it? Should it reload the homepage while you are still on the homepage, or should it smoothly head back to the header? Could you assess this topic in terms of SEO, User Experience and Performance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice for navigation links is to make them consistent across every page of your site.

One way to achieve consistency is to make *every* primary-level navigation tab scroll back to the top of the page, if the user is already on it. Logos aren't always perceived as Home links, though - that's why [Home links are recommended](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/homepage-links/) as part of your navigation.

An advantage of smoothly scrolling back to the top of the page from a primary navigation tab is that you're affirming to the user that they are definitely already on that page. A reload might force them to take a moment to reorient themselves.

So, my vote is for having the logo, and other tabs, scroll back to the top  (but you should test that with real users). I can't think of any performance or SEO concerns out of allowing this. Page reloads seem worse for performance, and keeping the user on a page longer is better for SEO.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate this comment :) I will consider the things you've said.